# How to configure Application Insights to only track the count of calls in an Azure Function App

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function App that is currently running and processing ~4k queries an hour. The application insight monitor is set to the default configuration of when it was automatically created.

I want to use application insights to track *only* the operation count per API call. All the other telemetry and log data is mostly unnecessary and driving up the cost to use. How can I configure my function app so that I can track only how many calls is made per HTTP method?

Comment: Hello, if the answer if helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Application insights, there is no way to directly to `track only how many calls is made per HTTP method`. You must track the `Request Telemetry` data, then use kusto query to do that.

Here are some ways to reduce the data:

1.Use sampling, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#configure-sampling) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsights) article.

2.Add a Startup.cs to the azure function, then use [filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

Another way I can think of to `track only how many calls is made per HTTP method`, is that you can go to the metrics of azure function, and see if there is a related metrics/filter combination which can generate the result.